# promise async await without .then callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I was trying to learn and better understand how promises work with new `async` / `await` keywords but there is a thing that is confusing.

In this article: https://davidwalsh.name/async-await

it says that using `async` and `await` doesnt require one to use callback, example:

```
async function parallel(callback) {
    const wait1 = wait(500);
    const wait2 = wait(500);
    await wait1;
    await wait2;
    callback( [wait1, wait2] );
}
```

if one would like to test it we need to define first a timeout function that serves as `wait`:

```
var wait = function(time) {

    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve( Math.random() * time );
        }, time);

    });

};
```

and finally we need something to call our `parallel` function and read values:

```
parallel(function(data) {
    console.log('data', data);
});
```

The problem is that if you read the values - they are a promises objects instead of actual values, to remedy that problem this could be done:

```
async function parallel(callback) {
    var wait1 = wait(500).then(function(data) {
                    wait1 = data;
                });
    var wait2 = wait(500).then(function(data) {
                    wait2 = data;
                });
    await wait1;
    await wait2;
    callback( [wait1, wait2] );
}
```

Now it will work, demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/jp3g2q5k/

But could you help me understand why i had to use `.then` callback? it supposes to be callbacks free situation. Or maybe someone knows how to alter this code to work without callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resolving a promise with the 'await' keyword. In your example that would be:

```
const result1 = await wait1;
const result2 = await wait2;
callback( [result1 , result2 ] );
```